# Spring MVC: How to save and retrieve records in one button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing POS application, i am retrieving product after searching the barcode (which is saved in database in product table), there is add Cart button on which i click will add the product details,price and quantity in order table in database and will show after adding to database.

I am using jsp,jquery on front end and Spring MVC on controller side and hibernate to interact with database

After clicking on add i am storing as JSON data making ajax call and passing data to spring controller and adding to database but how should i retrieve records too on add Cart click ? [image: pos product entry page c]

```
ajax call i am making
$.ajax({

        url:'/pos/addproduct',
        dataType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(order),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success:
            function(data){
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                console.log(data);
                var row=$("<tr><td>"+value.oid+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.pname+"</td>"+
                        "<td>"+value.qty+"</td>"+"<td>"+value.price+"</td>"+"<td>"
                        +value.barcodeid+"</td></tr>");
                $("#order").append(row).removeClass("hidden");
            })
        }
    })
});
```

The controller logic is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addproduct",method ={ RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody Order addProducts(@RequestBody Order order){
    Order orders=service.showOrder(order);
    return orders;
    }
```

Comment: Remove `RequestMethod.GET` from Spring controller's method. Add field `method: "POST"` to JSON inside `$.ajax`. You will receive orders as json in response.

Comment: Can you please add how `order` variable is derived in javascript. To me, it looks like, your request parameters are not mapped to Order object.

`data:JSON.stringify(order)`. 

How order has been derived or value captured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after removing  RequestMethod.GET from  Spring controller's method and adding method:"POST"